# How/where does Symfony comment <?php tag automatically?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to allow using the `<?php` tag on a forum through the `code` tag with Symfony 5.0.8.

Somehow Symfony (or Twig, I can't say here) puts it in between comment magically, and I don't really know where, how and why this is done.

I'm piping my data in my twig template through the `raw` filter obviously. Here's some code to visualize the thing.

Controller

```
public function show(Post $post) {
    $this->render('show.html.twig', ['post' => $post]);
}
```

Twig template

```
{% for comment in post.comments %}
  {{ comment.content|raw }}
{% endfor %}
```

Here's a sample of the text you could find in my database for the `comment` table

```
| id | post_id |                   content                  |
|  1 |    1    | <p>hey there <?php die('hijacked'); ?></p> |
```

And what's displayed

```
<p>hey there <!--?php die('hijacked'); ?--></p>
```

How can I allow the use of `<?php` tag? Is it safe? If not, how can I make it safe?

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://twigfiddle.com/ul1ka2. Are you sure the content of the table is really what you show us?

Comment: Hey, yes I am sure, I've tested my issue just this moment on a fresh symfony/website-skeleton project to make sure it wasn't any of my configuration that was causing it, and I still get the same thing. I've made a GitHub repo for you to test if you want : https://github.com/HeathSilcox/stckovflow61989201

Comment: This is very insecure. It gives authors of posts the ability to alter the execution of the page. They could, for example, echo contents of your ENV, which contains sensitive information like database passwords etc. Using `|raw` also allows authors of posts to inject js scripts into your page, exposing your users to xss attacks etc. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm using `tgalopin/html-sanitizer` to avoid XSS attacks. I'm just trying to allow the user to add <?php if we wants for code coloration in `<code>` blocks (combined with highlight.js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As made clear in the comments, you want to display the contents of a php script in your posts. You do not want to execute the script. That's already a huge difference.

You are using `tgalopin/html-sanitizer` to sanitize user input. In general, you want to sanitize when outputting, [not on input](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/95325/input-sanitization-vs-output-sanitization). So instead of using `|raw` in your template, call `html-sanitizer`'s `|sanitize_html` filter ([docs](https://github.com/tgalopin/html-sanitizer-bundle#usage-in-twig)). This will make a small but significant difference in output:

Using `|raw`:

```
<p>hey there <?php die('hijacked'); ?></p>
```

Which your browser will convert to `<!--?..` because it does not recognize `<?php ..` as a valid HTML element (and it tries to repair the HTML document):

```
<p>hey there <!--?php die('hijacked'); ?--></p>
```

Using `|sanitize_html`:

```
<p>hey there &lt;?php die('hijacked'); ?&gt;</p>
```

Because `|sanitize_html` allows the `p` tag and escapes the `php` tag, your browser knows how to render the page: it parses the `p` tag as an HTML element, and the `php` tag is just text. And that makes everything work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it helped to understand what was going on here. Though it still doesn't work with `|sanitize_html`. But I'll manage to escape the `<?php` tag myself now.